# Eclipse opens class file in an active working set instead of Java file

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

I have about 20 projects in Eclipse segregated into 5 different working sets. Main projects and dependent artifacts. Some artifacts are included in more than one set.

How do I set up Eclipse so when I control click a Java file, the relevant Java file from the active set is opened? At the moment, Eclipse opens a class file. This is while developing and not debugging.

I have followed every Google result I can find for 'eclipse opens class file instead of java' and nothing has worked.

There are no projects in Properties -> Java Build path -> Libraries (I have JRE System Library and Maven Dependencies)

None of the dependent projects are present in Java Build path-> Source.

My Maven is setup to download sources.

Everything worked as expected before I separated my projects to working sets, but was very confusing given the number of open/closed projects.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have disabled Maven workspace resolution.

In my setup, right-click on the project -> Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution
did the trick.

This way, m2e includes the Eclipse projects of dependent local projects instead of the jar files into the Maven Dependencies Library of a project.

Comment: I already have Enable workspace resolution enabled. As such when I right click, maven, it gives me an option to disable workspace resolution.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to disable/reneable workspace resolution? I remember some m2e versions which had some problems with this. Btw...do you have SNAPSHOT dependencies between your workspace projects or do your projects have non-snapshot version numbers? Perhaps, m2e always uses the jar dependency, when you have non-snapshot dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through what you described where I have multiple projects in my workspace which are inter-dependent and I would like to check the Java file against the class file from the dependency jars.

This is how I resolved this issue and open the Java file instead of the class file.

- Copy the Java class name (CTRL+C)
- Option 1: Open Resource

  - Press CTRL+SHIFT+R to Open Resource dialog
  - CTRL+V to paste the class name (optionally you can add .java after class name)
  - Result will have your desired Java file from different projects (and not the .class file from same project dependency jars)
    [image]
- Option 2: Open Type

  - Press CTRL+SHIFT+T to Open Type dialog
  - CTRL+V to paste the class name
  - Result will have your desired Java and class files from different projects (the best part is, the later part of the result set will have .java and .jar extension at the end)
    [image]

Option 1 will always show java files and Option 2 will show both java and class files.

NOTE: I am showing only partial file names in the images for security reasons. The images should give a good idea of what I am trying to explain.

These options may sound lame but they are effective, and work to serve my purpose.

Comment: This is how I am working around the given problem. But I need this to work correctly when I control+click a class name or click to go into the implementation of a method.

Comment: One more option you could try is, lets say you have 3 projects A B C. A have B and C as dependency projects so any java classes from B and C open as .class when clicked in project A. Add project B and C in Java Build Path for project A from (right click Properties-->Java Build Path --> Projects) and then move them up in (Properties-->Java Build Path--> Order and Export) and refresh the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Check into your project modules the Java Build Path, look inside the Source tab and verify if you have "Allow output folders for source folders" checkbox flagged; in this case you just need to uncheck it and you will be able to see again the right source from java files.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. And I fixed as below.

1. **right click** on a project.
2. **Maven --> Update project** (Alt + F5).
3. **select Project(s)** to be updated.
4. **restart** the eclipse.